# Determining product ID from URL in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, stores, product-urls

Here is a sample url from my company's Magento site (and we're obviously using stores in the URL hence the smi000.. code)

```
http://shop.mystore.com/smi130495/catalog/product/view/id/35830/s/men-s-traditional-ring/category/312834/
```

I understand that the category id is 312834, and the product id is 35830.  I understand how to use `Mage::helper->getURL()` to get the URL, but how do I get the product ID using magento code (i.e. the "Magento Way"?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the product id from the core_url_rewrite table using the url for this, try this:

```
$url = Mage::helper->getURL();
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->loadByRequestPath($url);

$productId = $rewrite->getProductId();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Also you could get the id from the url directly (no extra query to the DB) like this:

```
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```